# "Column does not belong to referenced table" Why?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, firebird-psql

This code should delete an album but I don't know why it still doesn't work

```
declare variable al_eliminare integer;
begin
    select count(album.id) from album where id = :id_album
    into :al_eliminare;
    if(al_eliminare = 0)
        then delete from album where album.id = id_album;
  suspend;
end
```

Comment: `where album.id = :id_album;` maybe?

Comment: Why testing the existance of the row before deletion... if it does not exists, the delete will not remove any row.

Comment: 1) `select count(album.id) from album` might be very expensive operation on Interbase/Firebird line of servers. It better be avoided. Or else, for niche unusual cases, better be issued very often and server cahce to be significantly increased from default. But rule of thumb is to AVOID `count`ing rows unless you really realyl need the exact count (which still only would be reliable in `Snapshot` grade transactions).

Comment: 2) your code makes no sense, it says "if there is no rows - then delete roes that do not exists; if there is some rows then do not delete them". It plainly makes no sense.

Comment: 3) using `suspend` there makes no sense too. It is used in `selectable procedures`, those that you `SELECT ... FROM`. But then the code should set velues for the output data columns that are supposed to be `select`ed from the procedure. Your code does not.

Comment: 4) frankly, using variable here is redundant. You could put your whole `select` into `if` condition and delete the variable. Yet better would be AVOIDING `count` - `if ( [not] exists( select 1 from album where... ) ) then delete`. And the best option would be just to remove that delete at all, Nicola is spot on there.

Comment: MAYBE you actually meant two different tables - but then you even do not need a procedure, just issue something like `delete from albums A where A.id = :Param and not exists ( select 1 from album_songs S where S.album = A.id )`

Answer (score 1):

When using stored procedure parameters or variables in a statement, you must prefix the parameter or variable name with a colon `:`.

In the delete statement

```
delete from album where album.id = id_album
```

The Firebird parser will consider `id_album` a column name, and no such column exists in the `album` table. That is why you get the error.

To indicate it is a stored procedure variable or parameter, prefix with `:`:

```
delete from album where album.id = :id_album
```

Comment: I changed it thank for the uspport but it do not delete the data yet, would you know how to make it work?

Comment: @OctavianFusari As Arioch'The points out in the comments on your question, you are currently only trying to delete if there are no records, so that will never delete anything. Change your logic to just call `delete` without the select count and if statement.

Comment: delete from album where album.id = :id_album; like that?

Comment: @OctavianFusari Yes